# MapReduce to removing duplicates of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapreduce

I have a map function which finds out domain names from email id & emit that one to reduce function which counts no of domains.

```
[
    { email:"xyz@gmail.com"},
    { email:"abc@abc.com"},
    { email:"inder@hotmail.com"},
    { email:"Ravi@Hotmail.com"},
    { email:"xxx@GMail.com"},
]
```

Here is the function

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.email.substr(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1), 1);  
    }, 
    function(host, count) { 
        return Array.sum(count) ; }, 
    { out: "hosts" } 
)
```

Output is good:-

```
   gmail.com
   abc.com
   hotmail.com
   Hotmail.com
   GMail.com
```

But what I want is

```
   gmail.com
   abc.com
   hotmail.com
```

I don't want to have domain name with duplicates with Capital letters in between & same name prior to <.com>. Any ideas how to remove duplicates with CAPITAL LETTERS. OR any relevant example is also good.

Comment: Change `this.email.substr(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1)` => `this.email.substr(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1).toLowerCase()`

Comment: No this doesn't work for me emit(this.username.substr((this.username.indexOf('@') + 1).toLowerCase()),1); Infact nothing comes after this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES5, you could do something like this:

```js
var arr, res = [];

arr = [
  {email: "xyz@gmail.com"},
  {email: "abc@abc.com"},
  {email: "inder@hotmail.com"},
  {email: "Ravi@Hotmail.com"},
  {email: "xxx@GMail.com"}
];

arr.map(function (item) {
  return item.email.substr(item.email.indexOf('@') + 1).toLowerCase();
}).forEach(function (item) {
  if (res.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    res.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using `Set` to get unique values:

```js
const arr = [
  { email:"xyz@gmail.com"},
  { email:"abc@abc.com"},
  { email:"inder@hotmail.com"},
  { email:"Ravi@Hotmail.com"},
  { email:"xxx@GMail.com"},
];

const r = [...new Set(arr.map(({email}) => email.toLowerCase().substr(email.indexOf('@') + 1)))]

console.log(r)
```

This code takes `email` property of each object inside the array using desturcturing syntax, then makes it lowercase and chops a domain name, and makes the result array unique using `Set` constructor, and destructure this Set into an array again.

Comment: your code is working fine , but you have to throw some light that what have you done in your code. Any comments for understanding would be good

Answer (score 0):

In the emit function, you can make it so that you return the lowercase of the domain like so: `this.email.substr(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1).toLowerCase()` [Info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

That way from all `GMail.com` `gmail.com` `GMAIL.COM` and so on, you will only get `gmail.com`

Comment: Tried emit function like this but nothing came. emit(this.username.substr((this.username.indexOf('@') + 1).toLowerCase()),1); . So it is not working. Have you tried this mapreduce function before posting as an answer